# Publish Custom Canvas App Event from Lightning Aura Component to the Canvas App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas, canvas-app

We're currently using an aura component with the `<force:canvasApp>` component to embed our Canvas App. As mentioned in the answer [to this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131245/how-to-fire-an-event-from-a-canvas-app-to-a-lightning-component), `Sfdc.canvas` is not fully exposed to the aura component.  I've attempted to load `canvas-all.js` into the aura component using `<ltng:require>`, but from the aura component's controller/helper javascript files, I can't get `Sfdc.canvas.parent` to show up (even though the browser console shows `Sfdc.canvas.parent` as existing).

Does anyone have a working example of firing a custom canvas app event via `Sfdc.canvas.parent.publish` from an aura component into the embedded Canvas App?  Any other way to fire an event from Lightning to the Canvas App?

**Update (Edit 1)**

As suggested by @rzr below, using `postMessage()` from the outer iframe in the Canvas App would do the job (you can see an example by @studds [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131245/how-to-fire-an-event-from-a-canvas-app-to-a-lightning-component) and `postMessage()` in action to communicate between Lightning and a VF page [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html)).  Only problem is that it is seemingly impossible to touch the DOM inside the `<force:canvasApp>` component as per [Lightning Locker DOM security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm).

Does anyone know how to send any communications from Lightning to the embedded `<force:canvasApp>` app?

Answer (score 1):

I think the canvas-all.js is only meant to be used in the app being canvassed, and not in any Aura/LWC component.

Is there anything keeping you from using the standard iframe postMessage API?
If you see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:canvasApp/specification) for force:canvasApp it states that the component takes a canvasId="someId" property that you should use for targeting events:

"An unique label within a page for the Canvas app window. This should be used when targeting events to this canvas app."

I havent tried this out but it might send you in the right direction:

```
component.find("someId").getElement().contentWindow.postMessage("message", "some message");
```

Then in your app being canvassed:

```
$(window).on("message", function(e) {
  console.log(e.originalEvent.data)
});
```

Comment: Since the canvas app is a separate component, you can't access the DOM via `.getElement()` (see the  [Invalid DOM Access](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_dom.htm) section).  So `component.find("myCanvasApp").getElement()` throws an error.  Otherwise your approach is right on target.

Comment: Here's how to use the `canvasId` to get the unique outer iframe identifier:
`const canvasIframeOuterId = 'canvas-outer-' + namespace + ':' + appName + ':' + canvasId;`

Answer (score 1):

The response I got from Salesforce support was that it's not possible from a lightning component, but I was able to work around it.  See my answer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=9062I000000Qzl7QAC).

> Since [using events between a Visualforce page and a canvas app](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_vf_app_resizing.htm) is supported, I wrapped our canvas app in an empty Visualforce page and used [this blog article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html) as an example to communicate between the lightning component and the Visualforce page by loading the Visualforce page in an iframe:

**visualforceCanvasAppPage.page**

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeScript value="/canvas/sdk/js/48.0/controller.js" />
        
    <script>
        function publishToCanvasApp() {
            Sfdc.canvas.controller.publish({
                name : 'mynamespace.myevent',
                payload : {}
            });
        }

        // Listen for lightning component postMessage and pass to canvas app
        window.addEventListener(
            "message",
            event => {
                console.log("message event", event);

                if (event.data.EXAMPLE == "example payload to Visualforce page") {
                    publishToCanvasApp();
                }
            },
            false
        );
    </script>

    <apex:canvasApp developerName="DEVELOPERNAME" />
    
    <!-- <apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.visualforceCanvasAppPage}">
        You can uncomment this to find out what the vfHost parameter value of the lightning component should be.
    </apex:outputLink> -->  
</apex:page>
```

**lightningComponent.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="vfHost" type="String" default="ORGNAME--SANDBOXNAME--x.xx99.visual.force.com" />

    <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/visualforceCanvasAppPage'}" />
</aura:component>
```

**lightningComponentController.js**

```
({
    sendMessageToCanvasApp: function(component, event, helper) {
        let vfFrame = component.find("vfFrame");
        let el = vfFrame.getElement();

        // post message to Visualforce iframe to relay to canvas app
        el.contentWindow.postMessage({"EXAMPLE": "example payload to Visualforce page"}, "*");
    }
})
```

**externalSite.js**

```
Sfdc.canvas.client.subscribe(
    salesforceSignedRequest.client,
    [{
        name: 'mynamespace.myevent', 
        onData: function (e) {
            alert("Hello from canvas app myevent!"); 
        } 
    }]
);
```